# DocuSign CreateTemplate API Not Returning TemplateId for Created Template

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign C# SDK, version 4.1.1, to create a template. According to the documentation, the CreateTemplateAsync method should return an object that contains the TemplateId of the newly created template, but that is not happening. That object comes back with all of its properties set to null.

Is there another efficient way to retrieve the newly created template's ID?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See code example here https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/blob/master/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/Controllers/Eg008CreateTemplateController.cs:

```
  TemplateSummary template = templatesApi.CreateTemplate(accountId, templateReqObject);

        // Retrieve the new template Name / TemplateId
        EnvelopeTemplateResults templateResults = templatesApi.ListTemplates(accountId, options);
        templateId = templateResults.EnvelopeTemplates[0].TemplateId;
        resultsTemplateName = templateResults.EnvelopeTemplates[0].Name;
```

You basically create it and as soon as it's done, you do a GET call to get the list of templates and find it as the first (newest) template.